# MFP Sql invocation fails using https

Tags: ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Am using MFP8, I tried invoking SQL adapter using HTTPS (Public IP) in PRODUCTION BUILD, invocation failed with below error

"com.ibm.mfp.server.js.adapter.internal.JavascriptManagerImpl invokeProcedure:194 FWLST0904E: Exception was thrown while invoking procedure: fetchSavedEmp in adapter: SQLAdapter
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException"

Same adapter is working fine in ANDROID Devices

Comment: The error result is very clear : "Exception was thrown while invoking procedure: fetchSavedEmp in adapter: SQLAdapter java.lang.RuntimeException". Please recheck if the procedure fetchSavedEmp is working as expected. You can add debug statements and redeploy your adapter to know more details on the exact failure.

Comment: You say same adapter is working fine in Android devices ? where does it is failing ,iOS devices ?
I suspect something wrong in your procedure code .
Try this command  `mfpdev adapter call ` in terminal and see if your procedure is works fine.

Comment: To debug your adapter follow this link [Testing and Debugging Adapters](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/testing-and-debugging-adapters/)